# I need to pull email size for each email in a sendmail log, then total them up with the total size and total number of emails

Tags: command-line, grep, sed, awk

The size is simple to find after size= 
i can find the size and put it to a file but removing everything but the numbers and then summing it with the total numbers all in one file is just not coming to me.

right now i am using this;

```
grep 'size=' /var/log/maillog-2019* | awk ' { print $8 }' > output.txt
```

Comment: Read `man grep`, and start with `grep -E -o --no-filename 'size=[0-9]+' /var/log/maillog-2019* | cut -d= -f2`. Then sum or count. Or, use `perl` (Learning required)

Answer (score 0):

I'll have a try with awk

```
$ awk -F'[[:blank:],=]' '/size=/ { sum += $12; total += 1} END { print "Sum: " sum " Total:" total}' /var/log/mail.log
```

- `-F'[[:blank:],=]'` Tells awk to process all kind of blank, comma and equal as field separator
- `/size=/` Select lines that contains `size=`
- `{ sum += $12; total += 1}` Select the 12th field and add it to `sum` at the same time we increment the `total` of one
- `END { print "Sum: " sum " Total:" total}` At the end print `Sum: $sum Total:$total`

For example :

```
$ awk -F'[[:blank:],=]' '/size=/ { sum += $12; total += 1} END { print "Sum: " sum " Total:" total}' /var/log/mail.log
Sum: 1491646 Total:800
```

I don't know if it will perfectly work for you but that should give you a pretty good idea on how to do it !